# Is it possible to create a List in Flutter/Dart with more than one type?

Tags: flutter, dart

Assume two unrelated classes (from Flutter libraries, etc):

```
class A {
   String name;
}

class B {
   int age;
}
```

Is it possible to have a `List<A/B>`? I know it's possible to have `List<dynamic>` but that would allow for Cs, Ds and Zs to be accepted as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a parent abstract class for `A` and `B` and add a `List` which only allows children from the parent class.

```
abstract class Foo {

}


class A extends Foo {

}

class B extends Foo {

}

class C {

}
```

This is correct:

```
  List<Foo> items = [A(), B()];
```

This isn't

```
  List<Foo> items = [A(), B(),C()];
```

And you can identify the type with your own variable or using the `runtimeType`

```
  for(Foo item in items){
    print(item.runtimeType);
  }
```

**Another option (long version)**

```
class Bar {
  final A a;
  final B b;
  Bar({this.a, this.b}) {
    if (a == null && b == null || a != null && b != null) throw ArgumentError("only one object is allowed");
  }
}


class A  {

}

class B  {

}

class C {

}
```

Usage

```
  List<Bar> items = [Bar(a: A()), Bar(b: B())];

  for(Bar item in items){
    if (item.a != null) print("Item : ${item.a}");
    if (item.b != null) print("Item : ${item.b}");
  }
```

Comment: I thought of that but I don't really own the classes that are being used. I guess I could write wrappers around them but that could get messy. Thanks so far for the submission.